# How to connect an xml layout with a view ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, canvas, view

I've kind of problem, I want to connect the XML layout with a view class
 which does painting. The main idea is that I want to draw over the layout.

**XML file**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_areas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/invert"

    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
public class TouchEventView extends View  {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
public TouchEventView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
{

super(ctx,attrs);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
int xPos = (int) event.getX();
int yPos = (int) event.getY();

switch(event.getAction()){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);

    return true;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);

    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break; 
default:
        return false;
}

invalidate();
return true;}
```

I have tried many things but nothing has  worked. It keeps showing a blank white screen.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and then include it in your XML layout definition.

Comment: How !! I've read something like this but i didn't know how to do it! would you plz be more specific :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like codes. for example

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.activity_my_vault, null,false);
        this.addContentView(viewToLoad);
```

Comment: The method addContentView(View) is undefined for the type TouchEventView